# Labels missing on first time load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am facing an issue with AngularJS directive/model load of my labels. I have a directive for building a table. All the header names, except the "Actions" one, are built dynamically by passing from controller as you can see in the snippet below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-cloak>
     <custom-data-table grid-options="ctrl.gridOptions"></custom-data-table>
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
function MyController(allInjections) {

    var ctrl = this;

    //Load some stuff

    ctrl.gridOptions = [];

    function initCtrl() {

        ctrl.gridOptions = {
            // all fields
        };

        // some other stuff
    }

    initCtrl();
}
```

The directive works well most of the time, but some times, mainly on the first time loading the page, for some reasons my labels are not loading. Look at the pictures.

The below image shows you the problem I am facing.

[image: table 1]

This table image is what I am expecting

[image: table 2]

I have added a log in my directive to see what I am receiving like:

```
function CustomDataTable(allInjections) {

    var _dirPath = 'table.html';

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: _dirPath,
        scope: {
            gridOptions: '=',
            checks: '='
        },
        link: linkFunc
    };

    function linkFunc($scope) {

        console.trace($scope.gridOptions);

        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Finally, after this and debugging in order to try to figure out what is happening, I noticeed that my directive is loading twice (I don't know exactly why) when the labels work. Look at the log

Log when the labels was not loaded well

[image: log 1]

Log when the labels is loaded

[image: log 2]

I am testing with the cache disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-cloak directive. The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Check this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: I am already using ngCloak in my div, as you can see on the html code snippet